# Wrong date displayed when converting in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I do not know why this snippet is producing 01/01/1970 for all the dates when I am sure this is not accurate.

My Original File:

```
Appreciation Start              Funding Date
    41266                          41432
    41266                          41715
    41266                          41533
    41266                          41505
    41266                          41444
    41550                          41513
    41550                          41451
```

My snippet:

```
import pandas as pd

df['Funding Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Funding Date']).apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')if not pd.isnull(x) else '')
df['Appreciation Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Appreciation Start']).apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')if not pd.isnull(x) else '')

df.to_excel('new.xlsx')
```

In Excel:

```
Appreciation Start              Funding Date
    01/01/1970                   01/01/1970
    01/01/1970                   01/01/1970
    01/01/1970                   01/01/1970
    ..........                ..............
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: In your apply/lambda function you're trying to parse the date in mm/dd/yyyy format which "41266" is not.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas is not able to decipher 41266 as a date. You can add a preceding zero to the date so that it looks like 041266. Then use pd.to_datetime

```
df['Appreciation'] = '0'+df['Appreciation'].astype(str)
df['Appreciation'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Appreciation'], format = '%m%d%y')
```

Answer (score 0):

[1/1/1970 is the epoch date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  It's what happens when your time is set to zero seconds and you want to format it as a date.

As for fixing it I would go with @A-Za-z's answer.  Unless you were going to measure time in seconds, which would make these dates around 1/28/1970.